# How to fill arrays with nan values while comparing two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays like

```py
    import numpy as np
    a=np.array([[ 3, nan,  4,  1,  4,  2,  2,  3],
                [ 2, nan,  1,  3, nan,  4,  4,  3],
                [ 3,  2, nan,  4, nan, nan,  3,  4],
                [ 2,  2,  2, nan,  1,  1 ,nan,  2]])
  
    b =np.array( [[ 2,  3,  2, 2,  3,  3,  3,  3],
                 [ 3,  3,  1,  4,  1,  4,  1, 7],
                 [ 4,  2, 5,  4,  4,  3, 10,  4],
                 [ 2,  4,  2,  1,  4,  1,  3, nan]])
```

Requirement :

> Where element value is `nan` in array `a` is assign in to array `b` in the same position.

expected output:

```py
             [[2, nan, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
              [3, nan, 1, 4, nan, 4, 1, 7],
              [4, 2, nan, 4, nan, nan, 10, 4],
              [2, 4, 2, 1, nan, 1, nan, nan]]
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: You could do a double for loop, and if you see a nan in `a` then you replace the same index in `b`

Comment: No need for loops. You can use numpy indexing. But first post your code, then we'll help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c = b.copy()
c[np.isnan(a)] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```py
b[np.isnan(a)] = float('nan')
```

If you want a copy of `b` instead of changing it inplace, use this:

```py
c = np.where(np.isnan(a), a, b)
```

Comment: Why don't just use np.nan?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Works just as well. I just never remember that one exists. Since the other answer uses ```np.nan```, might as well keep my variation